# Make a new list from two other lists of different types by comparing values of each type

Tags: list, kotlin, filtering

I have two Lists of objects that both implement an interface, but are otherwise unrelated. How can I create a new collection of objects containing only the objects of one of the lists that match a value in the other list?

Obviously I could use a for loop & do this manually, but I'd like to know how I can do this using Kotlin's standard library collection filtering functions.

So here's an example:

```
interface Ids
{
    val id: Int
}

data class A(override val id: Int, val name: String) : Ids
data class B(override val id: Int, val timestamp: Long) : Ids

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a1 = A(1, "Steve")
    val a2 = A(2, "Ed")
    val aCol = listOf(a1, a2)

    val b2 = B(2, 12345)
    val b3 = B(3, 67890)
    val bCol = listOf(b2, b3)

    val matches = mutableListOf<B>()
    // This is where I'm stuck.
    // I want to filter bCol using objects from aCol as a filter.
    // The result should be that matches contains only a single object: b2
    // because bCol[0].id == aCol[1].id
    // I'm guessing I need to start with something like this:
    bCol.filterTo(matches) { ??? }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A straightforward approach would be to search `aCol` for an object with the same id for each `b` in `bCol`:

```
bCol.filter { b -> aCol.any { a -> a.id == b.id } }
```

However that may become too slow if your lists are big enough.

To make it more scalable you can first build a set of all ids in `aCol`:

```
val aColIds = aCol.map { it.id }.toSet()
```

And then use `Set.contains` method to determine whether `b.id` is in `aColIds`:

```
bCol.filter { it.id in aColIds }
// or equivalent
bCol.filter { aColIds.contains(it.id) }
```

Comment: I wound up getting this to do what I wanted: `bCol.filterTo(matches) { aCol.map { it.id }.contains(it.id)}`. Any idea on how that affects performance vs. your answer? In this particular instance, I'm never going to have a terribly large data set (<=128 items).

Comment: @JordanBondo That's even slower than the first approach, since `aCol.map` is called for every item in `bCol` and then the result is thrown away. So it does not only increase computational complexity, but also imposes significant memory cost.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling upon this, I did some testing with both large (1mil) and small (256) datasets and found that while @Ilya's solution is indeed MUCH faster than mine, using `filterTo` rather than `filter` also had a significant performance improvement.